# How do I eliminate this "dual dock" in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, dock

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, and my dock is displaying in a weird way.

It appears the background of the dock is being drawn twice, which is quite unsightly—there is a dark, opaque rectangle with hard edges, then a smaller inner rectangle with rounded corners, whose brightness appears to change dynamically.

[image: Screenshot of a dock. The center of the dock is covered with a light grey rounded rectangle.]

I'm uncertain if this is a GNOME extension incompatibility or something else. My list of installed GNOME extensions is:

```
windowoverlay-icons@sustmidown.centrum.cz
auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net
user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
blur-my-shell@aunetx
apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io
apt-update-indicator@franglais125.gmail.com
clock-override@gnomeshell.kryogenix.org
caffeine@patapon.info
CoverflowAltTab@palatis.blogspot.com
openweather-extension@jenslody.de
pano@elhan.io
dynamic-panel-transparency@rockon999.github.io
ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
ding@rastersoft.com
drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

How can I eliminate this issue? I assume I'm overlooking something.

Comment: what gnome extensions do you have installed?

Comment: @Esther Good question. I updated the initial question with my current list of installed GNOME extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the usual suspects first. Disable all extensions except the "build-in" extensions (Ubuntu Dock, Desktop Icons (DING), Ubuntu Appindicators), log out then back in, enable them one by one until the issue reappears. Then either stop using that extension or file an issue to its developer.

Comment: In hindsight, that was obvious. Thanks. Found the culprit (User Themes), which suggests I must have a theme in my user directory that is being found and applied when that extension is active.

Comment: Excellent! Please accept the answer if it (at least provided the insight to) resolve(d) the issue.